# Finding What Populates Content Placeholder on ASP.NET Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

I have very little experience with ASP or .NET but have a need to make some content and style edits to one of such sites. The problem is that I am having a hard time finding the section which I need to edit.

In the main file called `default.aspx`, there is code like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Company_New_NoMenus.master" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" AutoEventWireup="false"  %>
<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

content here
```

The content which needs to be edited is located inside the `ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"`. I cannot find where it is populated. I tried searching the directory of the site to no avail.

If you use Windows Server, IIS and ASP, I would love some ideas about where I could look for it. Could it be set in the environment or be done in some other strange way? How would you look for it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So you don't have the source code of the app, but are searching the web application directory on the server for "MainContent"?

Comment: I should have everything for this app. And, yes, I was searching the web app directory. If there is a better way to do it, I am all ears.

Comment: I can only suggest that it is not actually in the HeadContent section, but it is populated in the master page (Company_NoMenus.master) file where this section is defined.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's possible these are populated via code behind or other C# code which won't be present in the web app directory because it is compiled. The web app directory generally only has aspx code, but no C#.

Comment: I think @Paddy 's idea was correct inside that file I found something resembling what I need. I shall see if making changes there does what I want. Would I have to to recompile something after that?

Comment: @MadPhysicist master file change *should* be automatically recompiled by IIS.  It watches these types of files for changes and should be completed quickly given there are no errors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14380443/84206

Comment: Honestly, if you don't know the answers to these questions, you maybe should get some help... Other than that be aware that changing the master page likely alters the rendered output for many pages.

Comment: I noticed that I have source code titled `Company_NoMenus.master.vb` but it is not present inside the web application directory. It is only present in source control. However, it does seem that the changes which I need to make are mostly in that file. Does it mean that I need to deal with compilation?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, that is a code behind file that is compiled.  You probably should go through some basic ASP.NET tutorials or you are going to come up on alot of hurdles.

Comment: That's what I have been doing. The problem is that whatever changes I make do not show up on the site. I have tried changing timestamp of the the `website.publishproj` file as well as other things.